# Install iOS Version of twitter on mac

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Is it Possible to install the iOS specific version of twitter on an Mac M1? It seems to be hidden from me.

Answer (score 2):

A developer has to choose to make their iOS app(s) available to the Mac.  If they do not, you cannot install them.